# How to escape a round bracket '(' in SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to use reference cursor for a sql query but I think I am missing >escape notation somewhere. I have already escaped " ' " but I am unsure about >the round brackets.

I am getting "international_flag : invalid identifier" error at open ref_cursor statement. I have tried a bunch of things to escape round brackets because I think that is why it is not picking the variable international_flag. Any leads will be much appreciated.

```
declare
international_flag          varchar2(4) := 'Y';
term_code       varchar(8) := '201709';
type stu_ref_cursor is      ref cursor;
ref_cursor                  stu_ref_cursor;
ref_cursor_select_statement varchar2(1000);

begin
ref_cursor_select_statement := 
    'Select
        CONFID_MSG,
        ETHNIC_CODE,
        STUDENT_NAME,
        POTSDAM_ID(STUDENT_PIDM),
        CLASS,
        LEVL_CODE,
        AGE,
        BIRTHDATE,
        fp_get_coll_box(STUDENT_PIDM),
        f_get_on_campus_email_addr(STUDENT_PIDM),
        RESD_IND,
        STUDENT_PIDM,
        REG_HRS,
        SGB_TERM_ADMIT,
        GENDER
        From  SEM_REG_STUDENT_NONGPA
        Where REG_TERM = term_code
              And STATUS = ''AS''
              And REG_TERM_STATUS = ''Y''
              And 
                 (
                   international_flag = ''N''
                   Or
                    (international_flag = ''Y'' And f_international_student_natn(STUDENT_PIDM) Is Not NULL)
                   Or
                    (international_flag = ''U'' and CITIZEN = ''Y'')  
                 )
        Order By STUDENT_NAME';

    open ref_cursor for ref_cursor_select_statement;

    end;
```

Comment: And what actual programming language are you using here? (make sure to tag your question with that information. It's pretty important to get the right people to see it fly by). Typically the answer is "don't create a raw query, use something that lets you create a prepared statement, which will perform all the necessary escaping for you", which most languages have available (but we can't tell you where unless we know what you're actually programming in, of course)

Comment: Hi Mike, I am using PL/SQL

Comment: term code: `varchar` or `varchar2`?

Comment: term_code is varchar but I kept it there only to signify that term_code is a variable

Comment: Why do you think this has something to do with escaping open parenthesis? Are you 100% sure your table has a column `international_flag`, spelled exactly that way? Could it be defined in double-quotes (in which case you must pay attention to upper vs lower case letters)? Does the SELECT statement run OK by itself, not wrapped within PL/SQL code?

Comment: Why do you think this has something to do with escaping open parenthesis?  - I had to escape all the ' and till then I did not get any error about international_flag variable. But once the escaping of ' was done I started getting invalid identifier error. I am not certain if escaping '(' is the solution to it, though. Spelling is correct, query works fine if I run it on its own.

Comment: OK... not sure why you get the error then, or - assuming my next suggestion works - why it works. Did you try the "q quoting mechanism" so that you will not have to escape the single-quotes? To create a quoted string, instead of enclosing it in single quotes and having to escape single quotes within it, you can enclose the whole string within `Q'[ ..... ]'`. See for example (Oracle documentation): https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty of dynamic sql is that you never get to know the error as it gives run time error only. The binding of variables should be check properly before constructing a dynamic sql. Here there are two variables like "TERM_CODE" and "INTERNTIONAL_FLAG". Hope the below snippet helps.

```
DECLARE
  international_flag VARCHAR2(4) := 'Y';
  TERM_CODE          VARCHAR(8)  := '201709';
    ref_cursor  sys_refcursor;
    ref_cursor_select_statement VARCHAR2(1000);
  BEGIN
    ref_cursor_select_statement := 'Select                
                                    CONFID_MSG,                
                                    ETHNIC_CODE,                
                                    STUDENT_NAME,                
                                    POTSDAM_ID(STUDENT_PIDM),                
                                    CLASS,                
                                    LEVL_CODE,                
                                    AGE,                
                                    BIRTHDATE,                
                                    fp_get_coll_box(STUDENT_PIDM),                
                                    f_get_on_campus_email_addr(STUDENT_PIDM),                
                                    RESD_IND,                
                                    STUDENT_PIDM,                
                                    REG_HRS,                
                                    SGB_TERM_ADMIT,                
                                    GENDER                
                                    From  SEM_REG_STUDENT_NONGPA                
                                    Where REG_TERM = '''||term_code||'''                      
                                    And STATUS = ''AS''                      
                                    And REG_TERM_STATUS = ''Y''                      
                                    And                          
                                    ('''|| international_flag||''' = ''N''                           
                                    Or                            
                                    ('''||international_flag||''' = ''Y'' And f_international_student_natn(STUDENT_PIDM) Is Not NULL)                           
                                    Or                            
                                    ('||
                                        international_flag||' = ''U'' and CITIZEN = ''Y'')                           
                                    )                
                                    Order By STUDENT_NAME';
    OPEN ref_cursor FOR ref_cursor_select_statement;
  END;
  /
```

Comment: Thank You Avrajit! I actually dropped the idea of using dynamic cursors, but I will try this piece for sure!

Answer (score 2):

That isn't how you reference PL/SQL variables in dynamic SQL. You need to use placeholders prefixed by a colon, and supply the variable with the USING clause. That can mean repetition where, as in this case, you use the same variable several times. You'll need to put in three placeholders and pass in the same variable three times (ie USING international_flag,international_flag,international_flag)

```
DECLARE
   TYPE EmpCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;  -- define weak REF CURSOR type
   emp_cv   EmpCurTyp;  -- declare cursor variable
   my_ename VARCHAR2(15);
   my_sal   NUMBER := 1000;
BEGIN
   OPEN emp_cv FOR  -- open cursor variable
      'SELECT ename, sal FROM emp WHERE sal > :s' USING my_sal;
   ...
END;
```

PS. It is better to prefix variables (often with a v_ but some people go fo l_ for local and g_ for global etc) to make it more obvious what is a column and what is a variable.